# How to check if there are more than 5 inputs given to read in bash?

Tags: bash, input

I want to take no more than 5 inputs, if there are more than 5 space separated inputs then it should ask for input again and display message "you have entered more than 5 inputs"

```
while true
do
echo "enter marks of 5 subjects"
read m1 m2 m3 m4 m5
if [ $m1 -le 100 ] && [ $m2 -le 100 ] && [ $m3 -le 100 ] && [ $m4 -le 100 ] && [ $m5 -le 100 ]
then
        break
else
 echo "marks cannot be more than 100"
fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `m6` to `read m1 m2 m3 m4 m5` and check if `m6` is empty or not.

```
if [[ "$m6" != "" ]]; then echo "too many arguments"; else echo "ok"; fi
```

Answer (score 3):

I would instead read into an array:

```
read -a m
```

You can then access the members as

```
${m[0]} ${m[1]} ${m[2]}
```

and so on...

And you can access the size of the array with

```
${#m[@]}
```

which can be used in testing whether you have too many (or too few) inputs.